# Set time has passed for multiple SVG's animation based on Javascript variable's value

Tags: javascript, svg

Currently I'm working on something that need to set time has passed x seconds for multiple SVG's animation based on a javascript variable value. I can get it work for single SVG element using this:

```
var start = 5*3;
var animate = document.querySelector("svg");
console.log(animate);
animate.setCurrentTime(start);
```

full code : https://jsfiddle.net/kxv3mueb/

But can't get it work for multiple SVG element

```
var start = 30;
var container = document.querySelector("#test");
var matches = container.querySelectorAll("svg");
console.log(matches);
matches.setCurrentTime(start);
```

full code: https://jsfiddle.net/c9ma2njy/, it should be started with blue color if time is set to 30s. It seems that I'm not correctly writing `querySelectorAll()` code.

it should be done by setting "begin" attribute value on all animate element using setAttribute(), but it's not working if I try to set the beginning value. But if I try to set the "`dur`" value on the animate element it's working.

```
var time = -15 + "s";
var b = document.querySelector("animate"); 
b.setAttribute("begin", time);

// it's work if I try to "dur" attribute value using this code
// the result I want is the sun starts on top, it's happened 15 seconds after the start
```

Full code : (https://jsfiddle.net/n4odcypa/)

Could someone help me get it work for each method ? especially using `queryselectorAll() + setAttribute()` method ?

I prefer to set All 's begin values instead of using `setCurrentTime()` method because I've set the time for all other SVGs using JQuery's css() method.

I tried jQuery's Attr() method but it's the same as using setAttribute(), it's working if I want to set dur's value but it's not working if I want to set begin's value

Comment: @RobertLongson but it's still work on 1st code, if you delete the script on 1st code, the sun will start from right, if the script is there the sun will start from center. So i thought that there's something wrong with querySelectorAll() code, not anything else.

Comment: yes you're right it's your use of querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

querySelectorAll returns a list of elements so you need to iterate over them i.e.

```
var start = 30;
var container = document.querySelector("#test");
var matches = container.querySelectorAll("svg");
console.log(matches);
matches.forEach(match => match.setCurrentTime(start));
```

Comment: Thanks it's work, but i still curious about using setAttribute() method, I always fail to set begin's value, but succeed to set dur value. Could you make it work too for setAttribute() method ? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m809y2gt/1), please look at JS comment for more detail